# Need Help Regarding Percentage Calculator Project

Tags: java, android

Guys I'm New In Android App Development, I'm Trying To Build A Percentage Calculator which shows required percentages when user enters input & Click Calculate Button

For Example : Input = 80

```
 Output (0.15%) = 80.12 [Formula i want to use (80*0.15%)+80 ]

 Output (0.25%) = 80.20 [Formula i want to use (80*0.25%)+80 ]

 Output (0.50%) = 80.40 [Formula i want to use (80*0.50%)+80 ]

 Output (0.75%) = 80.60 [Formula i want to use (80*0.75%)+80 ]

 Output (1.00%) = 80.80 [Formula i want to use (80*1.00%)+80 ]
```

**How To Do That In Mainactivity.java**

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Can you share your code? I want to see what you've attempted and how to assist you further

Comment: Your MainActivity doesn't even have any functional code. I would suggest you to show some effort to writing the code and question the community once you've tried. This way you can atleast avoid having your question downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can do it like this**

```
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcbutton);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tv15);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           int num = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
          // for 0.15%
          float fifteen_percent = (float) ((num * 0.15) + num);
          textView.setText(String.valueOf(fifteen_percent));
        }
    });
```

You can do the same for remaining textviews..

Comment: initialize Edittext Globally.. as you have initialized Edittext ip;